# How to know the Delivery status of SMS sent by at+commands in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sms, real-time, gsm, at-command

I use these following at+commands in vb.net to send sms

```
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CMGS="PHONE NUMBER"
>HELLO WORLD
```

How am I going to determine if it really send or it fails to send? I want to know the real time status of my message

I'm expecting like say for example. I hit send, there will be a messagebox showing "Sending" then after a couple of seconds, it will change into "Message Sent" or "Sending Failed"

Comment: Add a guess would think this is whole dependant on your SMS server responding in some fashion.  Weather that be some form of error response, time out, a simple boolean or otherwise.  Without a little more context, not sure you're going to get much more info sorry